# Localisation settings not saving

Tags: joomla, localisation, i18n

I'm running civicrm on a joomla 2.5 site and recently tried to update my localisation settings which at first appear to save but the new settings are not saved, it reverts to the default settings each time. I then clicked on enable multiple languages and since then I can no longer access CiviCRM at all in my admin panel - I just get the message: "Sorry but we are unable to provide for this at the moment. DB error: no such field. Return to home page"

Help!

Comment: Did you heed the warning about the "Multiple Languages" checkbox and back up your database?

Answer (score 1):

If you interrupt the process while CiviCRM is creating the multilingual mode, you could have a corrupted database.

If you don't have access to civicrm anymore, the best way is to reload a backup of the database as mentionned by [Laryn](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/26/laryn).

If you don't have any backup, i guess you could try reset the database to a monolingual by calling the function :

```
CRM_Core_I18n_Schema::makeSinglelingual($locale_to_keep)
```

with `$locale_to_keep = 'en_US'` or `'fr_CA'`...

You need to build a standalone script for this.